# Com licença ou dá licença?

Tags: significado, gramática, expressões

Qual é diferença entre com licença e dá licença?

Minha vizinha quando quer me passar sempre diz: **dá licença!**

Por que ela não usa com licença?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O significado básico é o mesmo, mas há diferenças - embora elas sejam sutis e facilmente suplantadas pelo contexto, intonação, preferência pessoal, etc.

O *Com licença* costuma ser mais neutro é a opção mais provável ao se retirar (para, e.g., ir ao banheiro ou atender ao telefone), ao se chegar atrasado a uma aula, reunião, etc., ao se passar entre duas pessoas que conversam (e.g., num corredor), etc. Um simples *Licença* é provavelmente equivalente. A expressão ganha mais ênfase com o ponto de interrogação (*Com licença?*), se aproximando do *Dá licença*.

O *Dá licença* tende a ser mais enfático e é a opção mais provável quando se trata de fato de um pedido ou exigência ou quando é preciso chamar a atenção (pois é necessária uma ação da pessoa a quem se pede - por exemplo, desobstruir um caminho) ou mesmo com a intenção de repreender. Nesse último sentido ela é até uma expressão de desaprovação: "*Como ele pode ser tão mentiroso? Dá licença!*".

Mas, repito: essas são no máximo tendências.

Comment: Muito obrigado!