# How do you say "Hey!" in Portuguese? Like, "Hey! What are you doing?"

Tags: português-brasileiro, uso-de-palavras

How do you get someone’s attention in Brazilian Portuguese, like "Hey! Listen to me!"

Answer (score 4):

Well, there are so many ways. Here are some:

> [any vocative - often combined with some of the options below]:
>    Você! / Rapaz! / Moça! / Senhor! / Garoto! / ...

Maybe the most common option.

> Com licença!

It's a polite form, also check [Com licença ou dá licença?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/5069/2764).

> Por favor!

Perhaps even more polite than "Com licença", but fitting only in situations such as asking for something or a question.

> Ei!

Colloquial.

> Ô! / Ou! [often followed by a vocative]

Also colloquial.

> Psiu!

Even more colloquial than "Ei" and "Ô", it might be considered rude by some.

Answer (score 1):

There are a bunch of different ways to call by attention. The regions from Brazil or if you are in Portugal could be different approaches. I would say:

- Oi! Presta a atenção aqui!
- Oi! Presta a atenção em mim!

ou ainda:

- Ei! Escuta aqui!

Source: [context](https://context.reverso.net/traducao/ingles-portugues/hey+listen)